# The meaning of "as though we were boarding"

Tags: meaning

> The wind was taking off in gusts, and the rain was putting down the
>   swells. I made out a patch of beach that looked less like death than
>   the rest of the arena, and I decided to drive in on a gust under the
>   spitfire-sprit-- and, if she answered her helm before she died on us,
>   to humour her a shade to starboard, where the water looked better. I
>   stayed the foremast; set the spritsail fore and aft, **as though we
>   were boarding**; told Sulinor to have the rudders down directly he cut
>   the cables; waited till a gust came; squared away the sprit, and
>   drove.'

This is from "The Manner of Men" by Kipling.
https://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/LimitsRenewals/mannermen.html

I can't understand the meaning of this phrase:

> **as though we were boarding**

Answer (score 1):

"Boarding" is a nautical term. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_boarding

The phrase simply means that the sails were configured the way they would be for boarding.